Upgrading to 5.75 causes PHP error
We have a installation on Joomla and want to try upgrading a staging site to 5.75 to see if anything breaks.
After running installation of the Joomla package for CiviCRM the completion screen shows indicating the usual database upgrade.
When starting it we get the following PHP error:
Ett fel har inträffat
0 Civi\Schema\EntityRepository::getEntity(): Argument #1 ($entityName) must be of type string, null given, called in /shared/httpd/events-copy/htdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php on line 275
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Schema/EntityRepository.php:38
2   Civi\Schema\EntityRepository::getEntity()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php:275
3   CRM_Core_DAO_Base::getEntityDefinition()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php:71
4   CRM_Core_DAO_Base::getTableName()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:480
5   CRM_Core_DAO::getLocaleTableName()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:144
6   CRM_Core_DAO->__construct() JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php:18
7   CRM_Core_DAO_Base->__construct()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Domain.php:61
8   CRM_Core_BAO_Domain::getDomain()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php:89
9   CRM_Core_Config::singleton()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:66
10  civicrm_initialize()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:87
11  civicrm_invoke()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:40
12  require_once()  JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php:71
13  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher::Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\{closure}()  JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php:73
14  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
15  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:143
16  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:186
17  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293
18  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/includes/app.php:61
19  require_once()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:32

This happens on all invocations of CiviCRM, as you might suspect from the presence of invoke and initialize functions in the call stack.
Upgrading to 5.74.5 does work as expected.
I would appreciate any ideas on where to start looking.
